# How to use TreeNode in a TableViewer in jface

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface, tableviewer

Inside a `TableViewer` I want to add Columns which are TreeNodes. How can I implement such type of `TableViewer` which has columns which expand and collapse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a [`TreeViewer`](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTree/article.html)? [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTTreeWithMulticolumns.htm) is a small example on how to use a `Tree`. Using a `TreeViewer` is very similar to a `TableViewer`.

It will look similar to this:

[image]